# Assertion error in fuzzy logic enough rules

Tags: python, scipy, artificial-intelligence, fuzzy-logic, skfuzzy

I have had use case for a fuzzy logic. I want to recommend a product based on needs. However my logic always errors, even though there should be enough rules.

---

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skfuzzy/control/controlsystem.py:586, in CrispValueCalculator.defuzz(self)
585 try:
--> 586     return defuzz(ups_universe, output_mf,
587                   self.var.defuzzify_method)
588 except AssertionError:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skfuzzy/defuzzify/defuzz.py:248, in defuzz(x, mfx, mode)
247 zero_truth_degree = mfx.sum() == 0  # Approximation of total area
--> 248 assert not zero_truth_degree, 'Total area is zero in defuzzification!'
250 if 'centroid' in mode:

AssertionError: Total area is zero in defuzzification!

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program gives an error because it doesn't have a rule for every possible situation. It's like trying to play a board game but you don't have instructions for every possible move.

To fix it, you could either:

1. Add more rules: This is like adding more instructions to your game.
2. Add a default rule.
3. Change your membership functions:  If the criteria are too specific, a
   rule might never get used.